# Cem Yuksel's "Mesh colors" implementation/demo?

Tags: texture, algorithm, implementation

Are you aware of any sample implementation or demo application of Cem Yuksel's "Mesh Colors" or "Mesh Color Textures" (http://www.cemyuksel.com/research/meshcolors/) ?

The author does not provide any links or pointers.

I only saw very few references about these algorithms, but nothing executable to see the results.

Comment: This is not an answer as I do not know of any sample implementations, however Disney did release something very similar to this. It is called Ptex. http://ptex.us/  Definitely worth looking at.